# Why isn't Angular2 Component property showing in my page?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my code:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <h2>{{secondTitle}}</h2>
      <main-page></main-page>
     `
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Lovely Jubbly';
  secondTitle: 'Bummer...'
}
```

title 'Lovely Jubbly' appears on my site, but secondTitle 'Bummer...' doesn't show. Only difference is how I initialized those variables. I'm TypeScript and Angular2 noob so it might be an obvious mistake. Could anyone direct me to some docs that could explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is interpreting `Bummer...` as a *type* (eg, a string that can only be `"Bummer..."`). When it becomes JavaScript, it will still be initialized to null.

If you're wondering, those types can be useful for certain enum-like variables. eg:

```
var trafficLightState:'RED' | 'GREEN' | 'YELLOW' = 'RED';
trafficLightState = 'Melon'; // ERROR!
```

Comment: Ohh... thank you very much. I guess there is no other way than to read TypeScript docs cover to cover :)

Comment: It is such an easy mistake to make, I do it all the time.  You could do `secondTitle : string = 'Bummer...'` or `secondTitle = 'Bummer...'` but it is real easy to forget the equal sign especially when half your time is spent in JSON.